# Como puedo hacer un push a un arreglo javascript del tipo {}?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Estoy intentando generar un arreglo dinámico del tipo{}

```
tabla.each(function() {

    var ID = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html();
    var fechaingre = $(this).find("input[id*='dfi']").val();
    var fechafin = $(this).find("input[id*='dff']").val();
    var canadul = $(this).find("select[id*='adul']").val();
    var canchil = $(this).find("select[id*='chil']").val();

    var pre = sessionStorage.key(au);
    var valorprecio = sessionStorage.getItem(pre);

    item = {};
    if (ID !== '') {
        item["id"] = ID;
        item["fechain"] = fechaingre;
        item["fechafin"] = fechafin;
        item["pre"] = valorprecio;
        item["adult"] = canadul;
        item["chil"] = canchil;
        var room = sessionStorage.getItem("users");
        array_room = JSON.parse(room);
        var habitacion = array_room[au];
        item["idroom"] = habitacion.id;
        item.push(item);
    }
    au++;
});
console.log(item);
```

Sin embargo al imprimir en consola item muestra error.

cual seria la forma correcta para generar una arreglo dinámico del tipo

```
{
    "ID": "1",
    "fechain": "20160101",

},
{
  "ID": "2",
    "fechain": "20160201"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te dijo Enmanuel, no es posible, utilizar push(), ni su contraparte pop() como métodos de arreglo

Lo que si puedes llegar a hacer si necesitas, por decir una agergación dinámica de propiedades, es tratar al objeto, empleando notación de arreglo contra él, aplicándole este trato a sus propiedades

```js
var objetoDinamico = {}; //hasta aqui es objeto
for(var i = 0; i<10;i++)
{
  objetoDinamico['propiedad_'+i] = 'valor_'+i;
  console.log('Propiedad agregada '+i +' - valor:  '+objetoDinamico['propiedad_'+i])
}
```

Comment: Esto es lo que necesitaba mapusoft gracias..

Answer (score 2):

No puedes hacer `push` sobre un `{}` porque es un objeto. Para poder hacerlo debes usar un arreglo o array (una colección de objetos), En ese caso debes usar un `[]`:

Así que, por un lado creas los objetos y por el otro los insertas en el arreglo:

Ejemplo:

```js
var obj = {};
var arreglo = [];

obj['nombre'] = 'Jose';
obj['apellido'] = 'Perez';

// aqui puedes hacer push
arreglo.push(obj);

var obj2 = {};

obj2['nombre'] = 'Juan';
obj2['apellido'] = 'Gomez';

// agregas un segundo elemento al arreglo
arreglo.push(obj2);

console.log(arreglo);
```

Tene en cuenta que el formato correcto de una coleccion JSON es `[ {}, {} ]`, es decir que esta rodeada entre `[` y `]`, algo que no pusiste en el ejemplo de la pregunta. 
Espero que te sirva, salu2

Answer (score 0):

para hacer un *`push`* a un arreglo javascript es asi:

```
arreglo.push({ var1, var1, var3 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta demás que te diga que la función [push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) solo está disponible para arreglos, en tu caso para solucionar tu problema es crear otra variable de tipo arreglo que contenga cada item.

```
var items = [];
tabla.each(function() {
var ID = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html();
var fechaingre = $(this).find("input[id*='dfi']").val();
var fechafin = $(this).find("input[id*='dff']").val();
var canadul = $(this).find("select[id*='adul']").val();
var canchil = $(this).find("select[id*='chil']").val();

var pre = sessionStorage.key(au);
var valorprecio = sessionStorage.getItem(pre);

var item = {};
if (ID !== '') {
    var room = sessionStorage.getItem("users");
    var array_room = JSON.parse(room);
    var habitacion = array_room[au];

    item["id"] = ID;
    item["fechain"] = fechaingre;
    item["fechafin"] = fechafin;
    item["pre"] = valorprecio;
    item["adult"] = canadul;
    item["chil"] = canchil;
    item["idroom"] = habitacion.id; // Posible error 'undefined'
    items.push(item);
}
au++;
});
console.log(items);
```

Otra recomendación sería que validez que haya al menos un registro en "array_room".